# Azure service bus - Copying messages from subscription to a queue using HTTP call

Tags: azureservicebus

we have azureSB topic - subscriptions and azureSB queues.
I have a requirement that from a subscription, I want to move the data (records present in the subscription) into the queue and delete the records from subscription. I want to do it using the HTTP call.
Something like mentioned on link -
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resources/move-resources#code-try-0

If you have a working template / example for that, please share.

Comment: What do you mean by "copy Azure subscription records"? Please edit your question and provide more details.

Comment: @GauravMantri - I edited the question, is it clear now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link you mentioned is for moving top level resources like Service Bus Namespaces, Storage Accounts etc.

What you are looking to accomplish is move messages from a Service Bus Topic Subscription to a Service Bus Queue. You cannot use that link for that.

One possible solution would be to make use of `Auto Forwarding` feature in Service Bus and that will automatically move the messages from a Service Topic Subscription to a Queue. You can learn more about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-auto-forwarding. Since it is a setting at the Topic Subscription level, you need not write any code to do so.

Other option would be to do it manually. Here you would read a message from the Service Bus Topic Subscription and then manually send that message to the Queue. For that you can use Service Bus REST API.

Comment: If I move the messages using REST API, that is highly inefficient when there are high number of messages. It takes a lot of time, I was thinking of a native solution here. But as you mentioned it does nt seem possible with HTTP  calls.  Anyway, thanks for your help